# Compiling and Linking GTK 3 with C project on Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, gtk

I believe this is not a duplicate question, I have seen all questions/answers before I post this question. I think I have a different situation here.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and downloaded **GTK 2 and 3**. I have copied a simple GTK source code from GNOME's website. But when I use this  command in terminal:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`  hello.c -o hello
```

I get this:

```
hello.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `gtk_init'
hello.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'
hello.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `gtk_main_quit'
hello.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
hello.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
hello.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `gtk_main'
```

here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int
main (int   argc,
char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if errors appear because I have two versions of GTK+ or what.
I'm extremely newbie in Applications Development in Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should compile with source file appearing before the libraries as `gcc hello.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -o hello`, the reason being the behavior of linker i.e it does not link the libraries unless the symbols of that library is seen prior in compilation.
Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, exactly! Quite odd and nerving behavior of newer GCC/binutils versions.

Comment: @H2CO3: Yes sir(/madam)! And it is quite popular question on SO too :)

Comment: this syntax works too:
    ```gcc hello.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o hello```

Answer (score -1):

You could also include the gtk library directly into your project:

1. In Eclipse expand: Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Cross GCC Linker > Libraries
2. Set: Library search path (-L) to path to file "libgtk-n.so", with n as your version. After installing (apt-get install libgtk-3-dev) on Lubuntu this was "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" for me.
3. Then add to Libraries (-l): gtk-n